# Unable to launch uiautomator in mac terminal

Tags: android

I am unable to launch uiautomator through mac terminal. I get the below error when I typed Android or Uiautomator in the terminal, or click uiautomator from tool folder.

> ERROR
> Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86‌​_64:/Users/ade/Libra‌​ry/Android/sdk/tools‌​/lib
> is not supported. Use -classpath instead. Error: Could not create the
> Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program
> will exit. logout Saving session... ...copying shared history...
> ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed. [Process
> completed]

My PATH is

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/ade/Documents/java_home) 
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME 
export M2_HOME=/Users/ade/Documents/apache-maven-3.5.2 
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin 
ANDROID_HOME=/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-to‌​ols
```

Comment: Have you tried using the command in the form `Uiautomator -classpath:/Users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib`? Alternatively, you could try some of the options in the related questions list.

Comment: I have tried everything and still couldn't get it to work. Here is the path I have set below.  export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/ade/Documents/java_home)
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export M2_HOME=/Users/ade/Documents/apache-maven-3.5.2
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
ANDROID_HOME=/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Answer (score 1):

You should not use **uiautomator** in first place.

The recommended tool by Google from Android SDK is [**uiautomatorviewer**](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html#ui-automator-viewer)

Which you can find in the same folder: 
"Libra‌​ry/Android/sdk/tools‌​/lib"

If you can't find uiautomatorviewer, please update your Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

After seen your path configurations, What I observed few needs to be updated as below:

1. `export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/ade/Documents/java_home)`
   should be like :[Verify in your local machine/ Sharing just to refer]
   `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`
2. `export M2_HOME=/Users/ade/Documents/apache-maven-3.5.2` should be like :
   `M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec`

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the current java version (I had Java 9 installed) and using homebrew to install Java 8 solved the issue.

Find the installed java version using

```
java -version
```

Then using homebrew

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

That should do the trick, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
export 

    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home

    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/android-sdks
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
    export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4
    export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Re-start mac

Type

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $ANDROID_HOME
echo $M2_HOME
```

And check for results

Also try `adb devices`
It should result your connected device
Then go to tools from Terminal

```
cd /Users/username/android-sdks/tools
```

Then type `Uiautomatorviewer`

This should open the Uiautomatorviewer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having JDK10.0.1 version on my machine and it seems not compatible with UIautomatorviewer. So, Uninstalled JDK10.0.1 and installed JDK8 and able to launch UIautomatorviewer with no issues. Thanks to all who looked into my question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed when I switch to a lower version(1.8) of Java. It seems UIAutomator doesn't support the latest one.

The lines in my `.zshrc`

```
# Java Home
# export JAVA_HOME='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home'
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```